# A/V Jack Turned Black

Tags: hardware

Today I took my Pi out of it's case and saw that the A/V jack on my Raspberry Pi 2 has turned black. It looks like it has been oxidated or something.
What could be the reason, and has anyone else experienced this?

[image: black a/v jack]

Answer (score 3):

I can’t really tell from the photo, but if you are wondering why the metal finger is discolored: try rubbing it with a cotton swab dampened with alcohol. If something dark transfers to the cotton swab, then that finger was probably exposed to water at some point.